# Print HTML table column-by-column instead of row-by-row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have a situation like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/xrrqzypL/

It is unknown whether or not the data-array has even or odd amount of objects in it, so all of these are valid for example:

```
var data = 
[
    {
        title: 'Title A',
        content: 'Content A'
    },
    {
        title: 'Title B',
        content: 'Content B'
    },
    {
        title: 'Title C',
        content: 'Content C'
    }
];

var data = 
[
    {
        title: 'Title A',
        content: 'Content A'
    },
    {
        title: 'Title B',
        content: 'Content B'
    }
];

var data = 
[
    {
        title: 'Title A',
        content: 'Content A'
    }
];
```

On top of that the table must be printed like so that every other row has titles and every other row has contents. To clarify, the jsfiddle I linked is a working solution, but too complex. Also, if there are odd amount of objects in data, then the last title and content cells should not exist just like in the fiddle.

My problem is that, due to the nature of HTML tables, I only know how to print them row-by-row like in the fiddle. I would like to know if there is a legitimate and a simple way to print a table column-by-column, because that would simplify cases like I currently have here.

To further clarify the problem, this is how things currently work:

[image]

And this I how I would prefer things to work:

[image]

Or simplified picture:

[image]

As you can see, the preferred method looks a lot more logical and controllable for data like we have here. So how can we print HTML tables the column-way, instead of row-way?

Answer (score 2):

You should use DIV instead TABLE. You can float DIV like TABLE using **float** attribute. Let me know if you need any further help on this.

Comment: I specifically want to use a table and find a way to build it column-by-column. The problem is not how to do it with divs or some other way, I want to find a way to do it with a column-by-column constructed table.

Comment: Take multiple variables on js, concate required <td> in particular variable and then combine it together when ever required. You need to implement some complex custom logic. Nothing else.

Comment: Does a library exist, that lets me type something like `<table><col><td>a</td><td>b</td></col></table>` and have it build the table just like with <tr> tags, but with columns?

Answer (score 0):

the logic is pretty straightforward

```
var insert = '';

var col1 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length/2; i++) {
        col1.push(data[i]);
}
var col2 = [];
for(; i < data.length; i++) {
        col2.push(data[i]);
}


for(var row = 0; row < data.length/2; row++)
{
        var rowHtml = "<tr><td>" + col1[row].title + "</td>";
        if (col2[row]) {
                rowHtml += "<td>" + col2[row].title + "</td>";
        }
        rowHtml += "</tr>";
        rowHtml += "<tr><td>" + col1[row].content + "</td>";
        if (col2[row]) {
                rowHtml += "<td>" + col2[row].content + "</td>";
        }
        rowHtml += "</tr>"
        insert += rowHtml;
}

$('#tbl').append(insert);
```

I also highly recommend using DOM (or jQuery API) to build the html instead of strings concatenate, because it is much more computer-efficient.

Comment: I am hoping for something that would let me construct the table with, say, something like `<tc>` (table-column) tags instead of row tags. That way the `<tr>` and `<tc>` tags could be actually changed on the fly.

Comment: The logic of table is row-by-row, and this is because each row always have same height for all of it's columns. There is no thing like <tc> and actually, nobody needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a pure-CSS solution-ish: http://jsfiddle.net/ahvonenj/L02z8bh3/
I think something like this would suffice.

I just flip the whole table 90 degrees `transform: rotate(90deg);`